# filtering in django with foriegn key references

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a view that is taking in query params and searching for venues which meet that query param.

```
 cuisine = self.request.query_params.getlist('cuisine', 0)
        if cuisine != 0:
            cuisinelist =[]
            for cuisine in cuisinelist:
                cuisinepk = get_object_or_404(Cuisine, name=cuisine)
                cuisinepk = cuisinepk.pk
                cuisinelist.append(cuisinepk)
                print('this is the cuisine pk')
                print(cuisinepk)
            venuelist = venuelist.filter(Q(cuisine1__in=cuisinelist) | Q(cuisine2__in=cuisinelist))
```

But it is not working in fact I do not get any returned venues.

the cuisine1 and cuisine2 in a venue object look like this.

```
cuisine1 = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='cuisine1', blank=True, null=True)
    cuisine2 = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='cuisine2', blank=True, null=True)
```

I use this method when I wanted to check relations within a room. I am wondering if I need to do the same? What is the correct method?

```
seatedcapacity = self.request.query_params.get('seatedcapacity',0)
        if seatedcapacity != 0:
            try:
                seatedcapacity = int(seatedcapacity)
            except ValueError:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            rooms = Room.objects.filter(venue=OuterRef('pk'), seatedcapacity__gte=seatedcapacity)
            venuelist = venuelist.annotate(hasseatedcapacity=Exists(rooms))
            venuelist = venuelist.filter(Q(hasseatedcapacity=True) | Q(fullbuyoutseatedcapacity__gte=seatedcapacity))
```

Comment: add your models.py

Comment: no you guys dont need it